# How to secure wrought iron gate

Tags: metal, security, gates

I have a wrought iron garden gate at the front of my property which grants access to the back of my property via the side of the property.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I was burgled last week (fortunately they didn't get anything) and want to secure this gate.

**How can I secure this gate?** I was thinking of attaching a padlock somehow to avoid a chain being broken by bolt cutters.

I'm aware that any security can be broken, but I do want to make it difficult to do so.

Happy to attach something to the wall or modify the gate somehow (I'll be replacing it eventually),

- I don't mind spending money on chains/padlocks but don't want to replace the gate right now
- I am capable of installing padlocks or mounting a bracket to the wall if required
- I need access to this gate once a week (to put the bins out)
- Security wise, I only want something which will slow an intruder down, not something to keep a tank out

P.S I know the gate is in a poor state but the issue right now is that I need it secured!

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], please take the [tour]. Define "best". Does it involve price, security, simplicity of installation, simplicity of access, something else? Around here "best" means "give me an opinion" and opinion-based questions are explicitly [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Please [edit] your question to ask a specific, objective question ([how to ask a good question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)) then we'll be happy to answer the best we can. As it stands, this will likely be closed.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @FreeMan. I've updated the question

Comment: Chain and lock.  Camera/s and motion sensor lights will make most think twice

Comment: Thanks, may be a stupid question, but where do I loop the chain? @crip659

Comment: Near the latch so it is handy.  it is to make them think of trying an easier place without cameras/lights coming on when spending a few minutes cutting the chain.

Comment: Thank you @crip659

Comment: Note both chains and padlocks can be cut using bolt cutters. Some padlocks are more resistant.  If you are able to weld, then weld a hssp or latch so it doesn't enquire a chain. And weld a box around the lock, so only your hands can just fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a hole drilled in the slide/bolt. It appears that when the bolt is slid to the locked position this hole will be just to the right of one of the members of the gate. Put the hasp of a padlock through that hole to prevent the bolt being slid back to unlocked.

If the hole isn't in the correct place, adjust the bolt or drill a new hole in a better place. I've circled the hole in the photo below.

[image: bolt hole]

Answer (score 0):

Drill a hole through the sliding latch part just to the wall side of that vertical round bar. You can insert a pad lock through this hole to prevent the sliding bar from disengaging from the wall.